# Why does my select box receiving error when i update it's data? PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, database, codeigniter

why does my edit.php is having a error i already check it with the print_r($variable name) and this is the output when i try to edit my data

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 5 
    [category] => 0 
    [name] => a 
    [active] => 1 
    [markup] => 1 
    [description] => a
)
```

this is my create.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">From Category</label>
    <select class="form-control select_group" id="category" name="category[]">
        <option value=""></option>
<?php foreach ($category as $k => $v): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

this is my edit.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sub_category">Category</label>
<?php $main_category_data = json_decode($category_data['category']); ?>
    <select class="form-control select_group" id="category" name="category[]">
<?php foreach ($category as $k => $v): ?>
// this is line 61
        <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" 
<?php 
        if(in_array($v['id'], $main_category_data)) { 
            echo 'selected="selected"'; 
        } 
?>
        ><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option> 
<?php endforeach ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

this is my controller in update() function

```
$this->data['category'] = $this->model_maincat->getActiveMainCategory();
$category_data = $this->model_subcat->getSubCatData($id);
$this->data['category_data'] = $category_data;

//print_r($category_data);die;
$this->render_template('subcat/edit', $this->data);
```

when i create a new sub category my select box is working and i can see the and choose a category for my sub category, but when i tried to edit it if i did not add this line "<option value="" >" it's not an php error but it does not show what category_data i choose as his category.

the error was:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

```
Type: TypeError
Message: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, int given
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Group6_Caps\application\views\subcat\edit.php
Line Number: 61


    Backtrace:
    
        
            
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Group6_Caps\application\views\subcat\edit.php
            Line: 61
            Function: in_array          
        
    
        
    
        
    
        
            
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Group6_Caps\application\core\MY_Controller.php
            Line: 58
            Function: view          
        
    
        
            
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Group6_Caps\application\controllers\Subcat.php
            Line: 180
            Function: render_template           
        
    
        
    
        
            
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Group6_Caps\index.php
            Line: 315
            Function: require_once
```

Comment: You talk about an Error! What Error?

Comment: Why is the `name="category[]"` as an array

Comment: Appears he's eventually going to make it a Multi-Select